# XAML проверка условия выполнения анимации

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть `eventtriger` на кнопки:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Width" TargetName="LeftSide">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="300" To="39"
                                         Duration="0:0:.3"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Как задать условия выполнения триггера, например, когда ширина более или равна 300? Если уже свернуто то, что бы не выполнялся.

Comment: А можно весь код кнопки?

Comment: Знаки препинания тоже будут не лишними.